# How to generate at once multiple PDFs with html2pdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, html2pdf

I want to generate at once multiple separate PDF files for each idsample contained in my MySQL database. I manage to generate one PDF without any issue but the others PDF are not generated. For example, I have 2 tables: `run0112201728S52PRO, run011220178FS22LEJ` and I want a separate PDF file for these 2 idsamples: `28S52PRO` and `8FS22LEJ`

my idsample is contained in the table name, so first, I query and substring to get the idsample that I store into an array. Then, I loop for each idsample to get the Lastname and First name.

Here what I have done:

```
<?php
ob_start();
//Connect to MySQL database
require_once 'configphp';

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
    use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

//define the name of the tables
$tablename='run01122017';

//GET idecht that we gonna cut from the result_array
$query2 = "select DISTINCT SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,12,8) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like 'run01122017%'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die ("no query");

//We store idsample into an array
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    $idEcht_array[] = $row2;
        
}

$index=1;

$arraysizeECHT=sizeof($idEcht_array);
for($i=0;$i<=$arraysizeECHT-1;$i++){



//Query to pick up Idsample information from PAT table
$FetchIdPat="SELECT Lastname, Firstname FROM PAT WHERE idEcht='".implode(",",$idEcht_array[$i])."'";
$PerformIdPAT=mysqli_query($conn,$FetchIdPat) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>
<h2>TITLE OF THE DOC</h2>
<hr/>
        <?php
        while($rowIDPat =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformIdPAT)) { 
        ?>
        Pat:&nbsp;<?php echo $rowIDPat["Lastname"]."&nbsp;".$rowIDPat["Firstname"];?>
<?php

$content = ob_get_clean();
 
    try
    {
        
        $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    $content=ob_end_clean();
    $html2pdf->Output($tablename.'-'.implode(",",$idEcht_array[$i]).'-Report.pdf');
        
        unset($html2pdf);
        
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }

    $index++;
} //end of the while
} //end of the for
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly makes you state the "the others PDF are not generated"? You implemented a loop, you should clearly be able to debug this and check at each iteration what has been created and what not. There is little we can help here, this is debugging that has to be done on your system. Only you have access.

Comment: @arkascha When I download the first PDF, the others are not purpose to download. I checked in the tmp folder of the server, I have only one PDF, the first one. I don't see my error, I put the loop to generate several pdfs.

Comment: In your code there are mistake and bad implementation, but these should not prevent the creation of the pdf. Do not use echo/ob_* to get the data, store them directly in a variable. You do not need the foreach, just do 2 nested while, $index is not used, you do not need to implode since the query return just one column, debug the first query and idEcht it return to see if there are really multiple distinct result. In answer, I post a cleaned code, it does not solve the issue, but it is easier to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You speak about download: keep in mind that http protocol allow **one** download per request.

If your intention is to:

1. do the request
2. generate all pdf
3. start all the N downloads

This is not possible.

Try to debug by verifies that:

- first query generate multiple result
- $html2pdf->Output() uses different filenames

Here follow the cleaned code

```
<?php
//Connect to MySQL database
require_once 'configphp';

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

//define the name of the tables
$tablename = 'run01122017';

//GET idecht that we gonna cut from the result_array
$query2 = "select DISTINCT SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,12,8) as idEcht FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME like '$tablename%'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die ("no query");
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
//Query to pick up Idsample information from PAT table
    $idEcht = $row2['idEcht'];
    $FetchIdPat = "SELECT Lastname, Firstname FROM PAT WHERE idEcht='$idEcht'";
    $PerformIdPAT = mysqli_query($conn, $FetchIdPat) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $content = "<h2>TITLE OF THE DOC</h2>\n<hr/>\n";
    while ($rowIDPat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformIdPAT)) {
        $content .= "Pat:&nbsp;" . $rowIDPat["Lastname"] . "&nbsp;" . $rowIDPat["Firstname"] . "\n";
        try {
            $html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
            $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
            $content = ob_end_clean();
            $html2pdf->Output("$tablename-$idEcht-Report.pdf");
            unset($html2pdf);
        } catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
            echo $e;
            exit;
        }
    } //end of the while $PerformIdPAT
} //end of the while $result2
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: thanks for the time past to help me. I tried your cleaned code, When I performed it it outputs me an error:`Uncaught Exception: TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file`. You said:`keep in mind that http protocol allow one download per request.` What if, I put all pdf in a zip file ?

Comment: That's because for $html2pdf->Output() default option is I - I: send the file inline to the browser (default). 
https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/output.md
As I wrote, it is not possible to send multiple files in the same request.
Yes you can put all file in a zip, Write them somewhere (option S), like in temp, keep all the file name, zip them and send to the browser

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanations. I am looking how to create a zip file with all the pdf reports inside.